# print CoordinateMatrix after using RowMatrix.columnSimilarities in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using spark mllib for one of my projects in which I need to calculate document similarities.

I first converted the documents to vectors using tf-idf transform of the mllib, then converted it into RowMatrix and used the columnSimilarities() method.

I referred to [tf-idf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/mllib-feature-extraction.html#tf-idf) documentation and used the [DIMSUM](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/20/efficient-similarity-algorithm-now-in-spark-twitter.html) implementation for cosine similarities.

in spark-shell this is the scala code is executed:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.HashingTF
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.IDF
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

val documents = sc.textFile("test1").map(_.split(" ").toSeq)
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()

val tf = hashingTF.transform(documents)
tf.cache()

val idf = new IDF().fit(tf)
val tfidf = idf.transform(tf)

// now use the RowMatrix to compute cosineSimilarities
// which implements DIMSUM algorithm

val mat = new RowMatrix(tfidf)
val sim = mat.columnSimilarities() // returns a CoordinateMatrix
```

Now let's say my `input file`, `test1` in this code block is a simple file with 5 short documents (less than 10 terms each), one on each row.

**Since I am just testing this code, I would like to see the output of `mat.columnSimilarities()` which is in object `sim`.
I would like to see the similarity of 1st document vector with 2nd, 3rd and so on.**

I referred to spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.CoordinateMatrix) for `CoordinateMatrix` which is the type of object returned by `columnSimilarities` method of `RowMatrix` class and referred by `sim`.

By going through more documentation, I figured I could convert the CoordinateMatrix to RowMatrix, then convert the rows of RowMatrix to arrays and then print like this `println(sim.toRowMatrix().rows.toArray().mkString("\n"))` .

But that gives some output which I couldn't understand.

Can anyone help? Any kind of resource links etc would help a lot!

Thanks!

Comment: make sure that you verified that you have transposed tdif RowMatrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following, no need to convert to row matrix format

```
val transformedRDD = sim.entries.map{case MatrixEntry(row: Long, col:Long, sim:Double) => Array(row,col,sim).mkString(",")}
```

To retrieve the elements you can invoke the following action

```
transformedRDD.collect()
```

Comment: Thank you... I will try this!

Comment: When I run transformedRDD.saveAsTextFile("...") and open the output file, I see multiple triplets. I am not sure what these triplets are!

Comment: @pranav3688 the triplets are the output of columnSimilarities() method
it will be in the format of row id , column id and the similarity between them

Comment: ok, but my input file has 5 rows, so I have 5 document vectors. The rowmatrix also has 5 rows. But when I am running the columnSimilarities() the resultant coordinate matrix has 12 rows (12 distinct row ids). Still not sure what's happening.

Comment: the `CoordinateMatrix` referred by `sim` has 1048576 rows and 1048576 columns. And the `RowMatrix` referred by `mat` has 5 rows and 1048576 columns. I thought the `sim` would have 5 rows and 5 columns.

Comment: ideally columnSimilarities will return a upper triangular matrix, inorder to remove redundant computations , for instance, if you compute similarity between A and B there is no need to compute similarity between B and A.
these kind of computations will be avoided.
so if you have 5 columns you should get 5*(5+1)/2 rows in your output

Comment: number of columns is not 5, number of ROWS is 5.
columns represent terms and their tfidf weights if I understood it correctly